# Page splitting animation using css3

Tags: html, css, animation, slice, divide

i'm working on my portfolio and i got an idea where a sword slices my div/page in half and then reveals the stuff thats underneath(see image :D). But i cant get it to animate, except for when i'm using an image that slides from left to right.. ( which is kind of a big image and messes up my site ) So i was wondering if there is any way to do this or if i should just flush this idea down the toilet.

See image here:
http://jvansuchtelen.nl/image.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Take a look at my ["wipes" plug-in for Scriptaculous](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/jameslab/wipe/) (2006) for some ideas. You can use a CSS background and position it differently in a bunch of cloned DIVs then you can move the DIVs around as if they're really big pixels.

Comment: There is a great tutorial at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/ on something similar (I think).  You can tweak the CSS3 animations to get the effect your looking for.